# Can I use Azure Maps tiles as a data source for Mapbox style JSON files?

Tags: mapbox, azure-maps

As far as I can tell, I have used the correct format for the URL, but on replacing the Mapbox style JSON file in Mapbox Studio, I get an 'Invalid source URL" error

I've looked at all the relevant Mapbox and Azure Maps examples, eg:
1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/rest/api/maps/render/getmapimagerytile
2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/rest/api/maps/render/getmaptile

```
...
"sources": {
    "azure": {
       "type": "raster",
       "url": "https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/imagery/png",
        "subscription-key" : "<my-key>",
        "api-version" : "1.0",
        "tileSize": 256
    },
    "composite": {
        "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8",
        "type": "vector"
    }
},...
```

When replacing a style in Mapbox Studio with one that contains the above source, I get an 'Invalid source URL' error. I expected Mapbox to be able to use that source.

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe that way:

```
"Imagery tiles": {
    "type": "raster",
    "tiles": [
        "https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/imagery/png?subscription-key=yourkey&api-version=1.0&style=satellite&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}"
    ],
    "maxzoom": 18,
    "tileSize": 256
}
```

Comment: I just tested this (via the Mapbox visual in Power BI, which is a wrapper around a subset of the Mapbox API) and this indeed works. As someone else indicated in the thread, this falls under the S1 pricing tier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Maps vector tiles with Mapbox style JSON files. However, the data schema of the vector tiles is different for Azure Maps than the Mapbox street tiles, so you would need to adjust your style to use different source layers. TomTom is the primary data provider and the source layers of the vector tiles are documented here: https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-api/maps-api-documentation-vector/tile

Note, the Azure Maps Web SDK uses the same rendering engine as Mapbox GL JS and is able to render data just as well. It has an easier to use API interface that is also less error prone, so you might want to consider taking a look at that. It doesn't support custom styles yet, but this is planned. Here is a bunch of code samples using this SDK: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Many thanks, however, I particularly want the raster tiles for the satellite view because the Mapbox raster tiles seem to be many years out of date. Frankly, it doesn't need to be Azure maps, are there any other sources for satellite views?

Comment: In that case you can use this service to access the satellite imagery from Azure Maps and add it as a tile layer to your application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render/getmapimagerytile Note that this requires an S1 level key to access the imagery (option you select when creating a key).